# Sending and receiving files in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need a way to let users send to other users some information stored in a Flutter app, and let the user that received that information store it in his app. I can send this info in a json file trough a messaging, but if there is a better way I can use it. How can I do this, and what's the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `share_plus` package to "share" files via email, whatsapp, telegram, drive, etc. The package uses the platform's sharing dialog.

To build the file you are going to share, you can use a different package. For example if you want to share the information through an excel sheet you can use `excel` package.

You can find more information about packages in pub.dev:

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

https://pub.dev/packages/excel

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

**1. HTTP requests**: You can submit the file to a server as a part of an HTTP request, and the server will then deliver the file to the person who requested it. The person who will be receiving the file may then download it and save it to their app. Making HTTP queries is made easier by a number of libraries in Flutter, including `http` and `dio`.

**2. Bluetooth**: You may transfer the file directly to another user's device using Bluetooth. Flutter features a Bluetooth plugin named [`flutter_blue`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) that you may use to send and receive files.

**3. Cloud storage**: You may share the file with the recipient user by uploading it to a cloud storage service like Google Drive or Dropbox. The recipient user may then download the content from the cloud storage service and put it in their app. There are various Flutter plugins available for interacting with cloud storage providers, such as `googleapis` for Google Drive and `dropbox_api` for Dropbox.

---

To summarize: `Bluetooth` may be the best choice if you need to communicate huge files or wish to transfer files without an internet connection. Using cloud storage could be a better option if you want a solution that is more dependable and expandable.

Comment: I thought about sending the file via some messaging apps (like whatsapp or telegram), but the question was more about what kind of file to choose and how to open it with the receiver app.

Comment: You might have to consider using whatsapp api's and you have to take measure to open different type of words